# Multer keeps giving me undefined

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm looking to use Multer to upload an image file onto my node server. The code is simple, I copied it from Multer's docs. I spent the whole day stackoverflowing this issue and it always comes back to giving me undefined for using ajax to send the image.

**Using a form DOES work**: [multer - req.file always undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851660/multer-req-file-always-undefined)

However, I'm curious to see if anyone have successfully used ajax way to sending files.

#### HTML

```
<input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar"/>
```

When the user clicks on the button and chooses a file, I simply display the file info, and use ajax to send the data to my node router
http://localhost:8882/profile

#### js

```
<script>
//files structure contains data about each file you load in
   document.getElementById('avatar').addEventListener('change', function() {

    var file = this.files[0];
    console.dir(this.files[0]);

    postItem(this.files[0]);

}, false);


function postItem(imageObj) {
  console.log("postItem <----");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8882/profile",
        contentType:false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data:  imageObj,
        success: function(data) {
            //show content
            alert('Success!');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            //show error message
            alert('text status ' + textStatus + ', err: '+err);
        }

    }); //ajax
}//postItem()

</script>
```

On the Node side, the code is directly from multer's docs:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

I keep getting undefined for req.file.

#### Node

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("------ /profile --------");

    if(req) {
        console.dir(req.file);
    }

    console.log("------------------------");
    res.send({"message":"ok"});
});

app.listen(8882);
console.log("index.js - listening on port " + 8882);
exports.app = app;
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit the entire form along with the image using `FormData`via ajax.

**Script** it uses *jQuery*:

```
$(function(){
   $('form').submit(function(e){

      //formData sets: multipart/form-data
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'http://localhost:3000/uploads',
          data : formData,                  
          contentType: false,
          processData: false
      }).done(function(data){
          //print response on success
          console.log(data);

      }).fail(function(data) {
            console.log('Error');
        });
      e.preventDefault(); 
    });
})();
```

**HTML form** Sample Code:

```
<form>            
    <label for="userName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="userName"/>
    <br>
    <label for="phoneNumber">PhoneNumber</label>
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber"/>
    <br>
    <label for="file">UploadFile</label>
    <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Node.Js** Sample Code, you can set the filename for easy access:

```
//file upload module
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination :function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'./uploads');
    },
    filename : function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,req.file.originalname+'.jpg');
    } 
});

var upload = multer({storage:storage}).single('avatar');

app.post('/uploads',upload,(req,res)=>{

    res.json({
     "fileName":req.file.originalname,
     "userName":req.body.userName,
     "phoneNumer":req.body.phoneNumber     
    });
});
```

Comment: After working through the example, there were some minor adjustments in filename: function(req, file, cb) that I made to get the code working. thanks

Comment: well filename is upto you, what u want to keep and how unique you want it. Rest, good to know it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your `node.js` code is giving `undefined` becuase multer attaches `file` object to `req` object. multer middleware parses only `'multipart/format-data'`, if data is any other format multer passes the request without adding `file` object and therefore req.file is undefined. So for your code to work you need to send the file in `'multipart/format-data'`. this link will be helpful in sending correct ajax request   [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

hope it helps :)

Comment: yup, like so:

    <form  class="uploadForm" 
        action="http://localhost:8882/profile" 
        method="post" 
         enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <!-- your other html controls here -->
    </form>