# Req.file object is always undefined, HTTP file upload

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm trying to upload a file in meteor using HTTP POST method and enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/api/v1/upload", function(req, res, next)   {
  console.log(req.files); //undefined
  console.log(req.file); //undefined
  console.log(req);
})
```

I tried with WebApp but getting undefined file property under request object

I also tried with multer and Picker but no luck.

```
const _multerInstanceConfig = { dest: '/tmp' }; // Temp dir for multer
const _multerInstance = multer(_multerInstanceConfig);

Picker.middleware(_multerInstance.single('photo'));
Picker.route('/api/v1/upload', function(params, req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files); //undefined
  console.log(req.file); //undefined
  console.log(req);
})
```

This is simplest form I'm trying to upload is

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Am I missing something here? not sure. 
Also, I don't want to upload files using base64 data string via DDP as it very slow.

I've check couple of link also with no luck
[multer - req.file always undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851660/multer-req-file-always-undefined)
https://github.com/noris666/Meteor-Files-POST-Example

PS: I need to upload images via native Android/iOS clients.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone, who has spent their time on my question, I got the solution for the problem from git [issue](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/issues/286#issuecomment-260790467), I raised.
I'm posting here my solution if someone else also faces the similar problem.

It was because of the name of this input field

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

which doesn't match with

```
Picker.middleware(_multerInstance.single('photo'));
```

changing either of them to will make it work perfectly.