# Strapi Image upload with Postman issue

Tags: image, upload, postman, strapi

I have a small issue. I'm trying to use Strapi rest api to upload image. I'm using Postman to test this out. So, I'm getting below error when uploading the image. Any help? I used GET request to get all my images and It's working fine. But Uploading is the issue. When I call the POST without a file, It will give me correct "Files are empty" response. When I add a file and try to upload, It gives me "Error: read ECONNRESET" error. In my console where I run strapi, I got "Error: Parse Error"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a postman or strapi Issue you have to put an API prefix in the URL
`Http://localhost:1337/api/upload`

Answer (score 0):

**I have found a solution.** This is not related to Strapi. This is a issue of Postman. Postman is sending File as "undefined". So in case if someone want to know how to fix this, Just close the Postman tab and start the request from the beginning.
For more info, Just see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851660/multer-req-file-always-undefined/38461398#38461398).