# Download JSON file from a node express server through my frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend

I have stored the file after uploading it to the downloads folder in my project directory.
I want to download that saved file from the frontend.
When I click on the download button, it doesn't fetch the file.

[image]

And when I go to `http://localhost:5000/download` on the express app, I got this error message

**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**

**Express Server Code:**

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    res.send('file downloaded')
    const file = './downloads/output.yml';
    res.download(file, 'openapi.yml', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log('file downloaded')
        }
    });
});
```

**Frontend App code:**

**HTML:**

```
<button class="download-btn">download</button>
```

**Script:**

```
const handleDownload = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:5000/download");
    const blob = await res.blob();
    download(blob, 'output.yml');
}

downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', handleDownload);
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**Update:**
Server.js

```
const uploadFiles = async (req, res) => {
    const file = await req.files[0];
    console.log(file)
    postmanCollection = file.path;
    outputFile = `downloads/${file.filename}.yml`
    convertCollection();
    res.json({ message: "Successfully uploaded files" });
}

app.post("/upload_files", upload.array("files"), uploadFiles);
```

Anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `res.send` ,which sends the response headers back to client ,which ends the request response cycle ,and when you try to do `res.download` it throws error. Use instead

```
 app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
      const file = './downloads/output.yml';
        res.download(file, 'openapi.yml', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log('file downloaded')
            }
        });
    });
```

`res.send('file downloaded')`--->remove this line

You need to update your js code as well

```
const handleDownload = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/download"); //http://localhost:5000--->this is not required
    const blob = await res.blob();
    download(blob, 'output.yml');
}

downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', handleDownload);
```

Comment: Hello there,
Thanks for your help
Now I am able to download the file when I hit http://localhost:5000/download this. But when I click on the download button on the frontend it still shows a same error message and downloading an empty file



script.js:24 GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:5000/download 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Now, it's showing this error message on the frontend "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" and this error message on the backend "node:19280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"

Comment: I cant see `path` anywhere in your question please update the question

Comment: That's a part of upload process , you should see this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851660/multer-req-file-always-undefined

Comment: I don't know why It's calling the upload route

Comment: At the time of uploading it's not showing an error message, but at the time downloading it's showing an error message