# multer : req.file is undefined

Tags: vue.js, express, multer

I want to send a file with axios, from my Vue.js to my Node.js,
but the req.file parameter is never filled, it's undefined
Here is the simplified code from my vue :

**Inscription.vue :**

```
<template>
  <div class="main_content">
  <h1>Inscription</h1>
  <div><input type='file' @change='openFile'></div>
  <button type='button' v-on:click="inscription" class="inscription">Inscription</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Axios from 'axios';
export default {
data () {
     return { selectedFile: null}
},
methods:{
    openFile (event) {
        this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    },
    inscription () {
      let fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('avatarBase64', this.selectedFile);
      Axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:4444'}).post('/api/testUploadImage', {avatarBase64: fd});
    }
}
```

My simplified node.js application :

**main.ts**

```
import express from "express";
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer')
const http = require('http');

const server = express();
server.use(cors({origin: true}))
server.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
server.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    })
  )

server.post("/api/testUploadImage", upload.single('avatarBase64'), async (req: any, res: any) => {
    // req.file is undefined PROBLEM THERE
});

const httpServer = http.createServer(server);
httpServer.listen(port);
```

Comment: Add `console.log(req);` What do you see?

Comment: Maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851660/multer-req-file-always-undefined?rq=1

Comment: in my req I see a req.body.avatarBase64 with juste a __proto__ object but the rest is empty, and the req.file is undefined : https://ibb.co/Q8R0md5

Comment: Hi Michael, i saw this post, but i am not in a form in this situation, maybe i am forced to be in a html form to send a file ?

Comment: Did you try `server.post(...).then(...)` instead of passing handler as an argument?

Comment: doesnt change, my req.file is still undefined, thanks for the proposition

Answer (score 2):

try changing **headers** of axios with

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

Comment: Thx Moe, i tried and i got a new error 'Boundary no found' and the solution to this error is to remove the 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data', so i go round in circles

Answer (score 0):

I found out : i was sending this

```
Axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:4444'}).post('/api/testUploadImage', {avatarBase64: fd});
```

instead of this :

```
Axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:4444'}).post('/api/testUploadImage', fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your multer version and try it agian

npm i multer@2.0.0-rc.2

and edit this:

```
    Axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:4444'}).post('/api/testUploadImage', fd);
```